# Crestron SIMPL Text Entry Field Initializing

Tags: logic

I am trying to program the system where you choose day of week and in a text field next to it you should be able to chose the time of the day in increment of 15 min + or -. Which of joins should I use for txt field and how to put default time in the field?

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to use an initialised value for the default time and have it incremented +/- as needed. Text entry join numbers can be the same as text feedback joins but it's better to use different ones.

Comment: Thank you! A lot of time gone from that issue, but it is always interesting to know how to solve something you were struggling with :-) thanks again!